# EF: Entity Dependency injection

Tags: entity-framework, orm, domain-driven-design

Does EF 6 allow dependency injection in my entities? Below is an example of what is needed.

```
class User
{
    private IPasswordEncryptor _passwordEncryptor;

    public User(IPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor)
    {
       _passwordEncryptor = passwordEncryptor;
    }

    ...
}
```

So, I need to find a way to inject the IPasswordEncryptor into User in Entity Framework. It's a general question, I just provided an example above.

Comment: You may want to reconsider this. See http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/03/04/How-not-to-inject-services-in-entities

Comment: Entities as any other objects might have external dependencies. It's just OOP. From my point of view, a given framework like EF shouldn't be an obstacle for excluding entity dependencies. NHibernate, for example, allows injecting the dependencies. The example above is a good example why this dependency is needed. User is responsible for managing the password. However, User is not concerned how the encryption is implemented and what algorithm is chosen. Therefore it depends on IPasswordEncryptor.

Comment: Ever find out a way to do it Markus? I have a pretty good use case.

Answer (score 2):

> For those using a DI container, you might try to inject the
>   dependencies into the aggregate root.  That leads to a whole host of
>   problems, which are so numerous I won’t derail a perfectly good post
>   by getting into it.  Instead, there’s another, more
>   intention-revealing option: the double dispatch pattern.

Quoted from a post by Jimmy Bogard. Find that post (which includes an example) here: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/03/30/strengthening-your-domain-the-double-dispatch-pattern/.